# Preparing for careers outside academia

Tags: industry

I'm currently beginning a master's program in physics. I intend to pursue a PhD after this. I am interested in theory and at this point I think I want to explore high energy or stat mech and/or its applications. I understand that it can be quite difficult to get a good faculty position even after a few years of post-doc work. I am also interested in fields like economics and finance, and I understand that a number of physics (and math) PhD grads end up working in fields like quant finance, corporate finance or consulting. I've taken some basic courses in economics and finance (all online), but  I would like to know how to actually prepare for such careers. I'd definitely love to work in academia but I'm also a little scared (and realistic, maybe) because of the sheer competition there is, and how uncertain it seems to be.
Preparation could be in terms of taking on extra courses, or taking up licenses/certification exams. If there are internships I need to do, how would those work out? I'm quite clueless at this point, but I hope I'm not too late.

Thanks!

Comment: This is off-topic here since you are asking about jobs outside academia.

Comment: Learn to code -- being able to put your mathematical ideas/solutions into something that can be physically implemented will make you very valuable.